# What happens when I play a Swindler and no cards with the same cost as the trashed card are in the kingdom set?

Tags: dominion, dominion-intrigue, dominion-promotional

> Swindler: +2 Coins, Each other player trashes the top card of his deck and gains a card with the same cost that you choose.

Say my opponent has played a [Black Market](http://dominion.diehrstraits.com/?card=blackmarket) and now the top card of their deck is a 4-cost card they purchased with it. There are no cards in the kingdom set that cost 4, and I play my Swindler. My opponent trashes the 4-cost card from the top of his deck, but what, if anything, does he gain since there are no other 4-cost cards in the kingdom set?

Answer (score 15):

As always in Dominion, you do as much as you can of what the card instructs. Since there is no card to gain that has the same cost, your opponent gains nothing. You still trash the card that was turned over because you can do that part of the card's instructions.

Comment: Its funny when a swindler starts turning curses back into coppers as the curse pile is empty, haven't seen a swindler start trashing them though!